# Unable to deliver mail with Outlook SMTP using C#

Tags: c#, outlook, smtpclient

I'm trying to send Email from my C# application. I'm using `SmtpClient` class and Outlook SMTP server to perform this operation.

Here's my code :

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string _sender = "testFromMail@outlook.com";
    string _password = "myTestPassword";

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com");

    client.Port = 587;
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials =
        new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_sender, _password);
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Credentials = credentials;

    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(_sender, "testToMail.com");
    message.Subject = "new subj";
    message.Body = "new body";
    client.Send(message);
}
```

My code runs successfully without throwing any exceptions.

The problem is, the email doesn't get delivered to the recipient. When I open the Inbox of the sender's mail, it says the mail couldn't get delivered because 
it had triggered junk filters.

[image: Screenshot of the Failed Mail]

I assume this has to do with any parameter not being sent to the SMTP client class, or any security settings that I need to configure in the sender's mail.

Any suggestion would be of great help!

Comment: Is `"testToMail.com"` a valid recipient address?

Comment: Yes. The from and to mail address, and the password is valid.

Comment: Maybe "new subj" looks like a generated spam subject? Try putting something more meaningful in there, and maybe a bit longer body? Who knows what those junk filters see as junk? Anything that looks generated would qualify, though, I guess.

Comment: I tried adding bigger and meaningful subjects and messages. I end up with Failed Mail :( Is the PortNo and the smtp server url correct ?

Comment: @RanjithV I found [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/oemail-osend/sending-emails-not-working-anymore-remote-server/6d02bb8f-2991-4549-9561-7158fb13060a) in the Microsoft forums. May you give this a try

Comment: @Martin Thanks for the link. But the issue still occurs :(

Answer (score 0):

Error [5.4.0](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/284204/delivery-status-notifications-in-exchange-server-and-in-small-business) means there's a DNS / name lookup problem. In this case it's because you're trying to send a mail to 'testToMail.com'. This is not a valid email address.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string fromMail = "sender.email@outlook.com";
        string fromPassword = "sender_email_password";

        MailMessage message= new MailMessage(); 
        message.From = new MailAddress(fromMail);
        message.Subject = "Test Subject";
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("receiver.email@outlook.com"));
        message.Body = "testing mail";
        message.IsBodyHtml= true;

        //message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:\Users\Desktop"));//--Uncomment this to send any attachment  

        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com")
        {
            Port = 587,
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromMail, fromPassword),
            EnableSsl = true,

        };

        smtpClient.Send(message);

        Console.WriteLine("sent sucess");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).